# How to trigger mouseover info

Tags: windows-10

When hovering the cursor over something, after a second or so, a little bit of info appears. Sometimes it can take longer, and sometimes it won't appear at all. Is there a way of triggering it to appear?

For example, in Outlook, I hover over a contact's name to see their email address. Sometimes this is instant, sometimes there's a delay, and sometimes it won't happen at all. The above is an example only. My question pertains to Windows and not specifically Outlook.

Comment: Tooltips (mouseover info you're referring to) are usually set on labels, rather than speicific fields on a table/grid. You might need to find the sweet-spot on the label.

Comment: Outlook also only shows a tooltip if there is extra information that does not fit where the name and address were, such as a photo or job description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no general soltion. As it's an application and/or website dependent implementation. A program might do any number of things to gather the information to be displayed so it might even vary within the same application.